# 1С programming (конфигурация)

Tags: битрикс, 1с

В 1С  как написать код для поле ввода калькулятора чтобы там не могли вводить буквы из клавиатуру но цифры могли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбери тип реквизита - число, разумеется указав длину и точность
(ПКМ на реквизит -> свойства)

Конечно если хочется именно в строковом реквизите - можно пойти:
        либо через обработку событий реквизита, например событие "ИзменениеТекста", находится в свойствах элемента формы;
        либо отлавливать событие нажатия клавиши через Wscript.Shell и обрабатывать ввод

Но рекомендуется просто использовать подходящий тип